# In Firebase database what is more expensive. Attaching or doing recursive calls

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

### Scenario:

- phone performs an action that triggers a firebase function
- firebase function will write to the realtime database when finished
- phone knows exactly where firebase function will write

### Question 1:

What is cheaper?

1.**Attaching** to that location until value is not nil or

2.**Repeatedly fetching** the location until value is not nil.

### Question 2:

Does repeated fetch that returns nil incur protocol overhead calls (like http or ssl for example). A theoretical example: Suppose I were fetch 1 billion times from a location that doesn't exist (has value nil). Will google charge me for these calls?

Another theoretical: Suppose 1 billion phones were to do one call each to a nil value. Will google charge for this?

### Experiment I did:

I've been attaching to the location this whole time but decided to get data on repeated fetching.

Code I ran (turned to pseudo):

```
func recursiveFetch() {
    Log.test("Another call")
    firebaseFetch(withKey: "abc123") { (data: [String:Any]) in

        if data != nil {
            //complete
        } else {
            recursiveFetch()
        }
    }
}
```

Results:

With normal wifi it recursively did 9 calls before getting a result.

```
Persistance Off normal Wifi
19:58:10.721 TEST  ❇️❇️❇️❇️ in EpisodeCellPresenter.swift:updatePinButtonLabelAfterAction():56:: Another call
19:58:10.842 TEST  ❇️❇️❇️❇️ in EpisodeCellPresenter.swift:updatePinButtonLabelAfterAction():56:: Another call
19:58:10.931 TEST  ❇️❇️❇️❇️ in EpisodeCellPresenter.swift:updatePinButtonLabelAfterAction():56:: Another call
19:58:11.051 TEST  ❇️❇️❇️❇️ in EpisodeCellPresenter.swift:updatePinButtonLabelAfterAction():56:: Another call
19:58:11.118 TEST  ❇️❇️❇️❇️ in EpisodeCellPresenter.swift:updatePinButtonLabelAfterAction():56:: Another call
19:58:11.235 TEST  ❇️❇️❇️❇️ in EpisodeCellPresenter.swift:updatePinButtonLabelAfterAction():56:: Another call
19:58:11.316 TEST  ❇️❇️❇️❇️ in EpisodeCellPresenter.swift:updatePinButtonLabelAfterAction():56:: Another call
19:58:11.427 TEST  ❇️❇️❇️❇️ in EpisodeCellPresenter.swift:updatePinButtonLabelAfterAction():56:: Another call
19:58:11.499 TEST  ❇️❇️❇️❇️ in EpisodeCellPresenter.swift:updatePinButtonLabelAfterAction():56:: Another call
```

With high latency wifi it took 2 calls.

```
persistance off high latency
19:59:06.655 TEST  ❇️❇️❇️❇️ in EpisodeCellPresenter.swift:updatePinButtonLabelAfterAction():56:: Another call
19:59:06.737 TEST  ❇️❇️❇️❇️ in EpisodeCellPresenter.swift:updatePinButtonLabelAfterAction():56:: Another call
```

### The money question for my situation

Is doing 9 consecutive calls to a nil location, then finally getting a result on the 10th attempt *more OR less* expensive than attaching to that location?

Answer (score 0):

You just want to listen to the location that you know is going to change when the work is complete, then stop listening.  Anything else is a waste of time and code.

Comment: Thanks! I don't think I conveyed what I wanted with my question well enough. The goal is to either attach or keep fetching a location until an item appears there. Once the item appears then I stop fetching / attaching. What is the cheapest way to accomplish this goal? Should I attach once and wait or should I repeatedly fetch?

In my case, I fetched 9 nils before I the result came in. Is doing this cheaper than attaching and waiting given that there are http and ssl protocol overheads?

Comment: I understood what you were asking.  I can't think of *any* case where you'd want to repeatedly listen and stop listening to a location. You could just listen once and stop listening when you receive the result you're looking for.  If you still feel I'm misunderstanding you, please edit your question to show *exactly* what you're doing in both cases. No pseudocode.

Comment: In my exact case a user has a "pin" button to add an item to a list. When they press the "pin" button a query is sent to google function which does some operation. Once the operation is done the item is added to a list. One the item is added to the list the button changes from "pin" to "unpin". In this case I know exactly where the list is and what key to look for in that list. I can attach to that location and get an update (which is easy to code) or I can poll that location. I want to know which is cheaper. Hope that helps?

Comment: My answer still applies.  It's a waste of resources to keep fetching something repeatedly when you could just listen to the location where it will appear.